# Count the different dates of each users mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table called `order_match` which contain columns `createdby` as the buyer, `createdAt` as the date of transaction, and `order_status_Id` as the order_status.

If `order_status_id` is (4, 5, 6, 8) then the transaction are approved, so I want to count every different days of each buyer so I know the gap of each buyer to doing new transaction after the last transaction.

After that, I can determine the `max` day of the longest transaction gap, and the `minimum` day, and the `average` of the buyers on that range to doing transaction

This is the example data of the transaction between 2018-12-01 until 2018-12-04

```
    +-----------+------------+-----------------+
    | createdby | createdAt  | order_status_id |
    +-----------+------------+-----------------+
    |         A | 2018-12-01 |               4 |
    |         A | 2018-12-02 |               5 |
    |         A | 2018-12-04 |               5 |
    |         B | 2018-12-02 |               5 |
    |         B | 2018-12-04 |               5 |
    |         C | 2018-12-03 |               5 |
    |         C | 2018-12-04 |               6 |
    +-----------+------------+-----------------+
```

From that data, what expected results is :

```
+-------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------+
|            max day            | min day |    average day of the transaction     |
+-------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------+
| 2 (the transaction on         |       1 | 1,5 (average from each gap            |
| buyer "A" ('2018-12-02' to    |         | day / of the gap transaction held) |
| '2018-12-04) and "B"          |         |                                       |
| ('2018-12-02' to '2018-12-04) |         |                                       |
+-------------------------------+---------+---------------------------------------+
```

The point is I want to count time lag in days between every two consecutive purchases made by the buyer within the selected time frame. the difference in days also calculates the time lag between the last purchase before the selected time range (if any) and the first purchase in the selected time range.

This is my progress syntax

```
SELECT 
    SUM((DATEDIFF(GREATEST(om1.createdAt, '2018-12-18'), 
                  LEAST(om2.createdAt, '2018-12-20')) * -1) + 1)
FROM order_match om1, order_match om2 
WHERE om1.createdAt <='2018-12-20' 
  AND om2.createdAt >= '2018-12-18' 
  AND om1.order_status_Id IN (4, 5, 6, 8) 
GROUP BY om1.createdby;
```

Comment: Whathave you tried so far? and which mysql Version do you use.

Comment: Shouldn't the buyer appear in your expected output and why does 1 not appear as max for buyer 3? And I don't understand your average calculation.

Comment: i used MySQL Workbench and let me add my progress syntax @nbk

Comment: it looks ambigous because createdby (the buyer) and the expected results are the same type of number, let me edit the buyer data type @P.Salmon

Comment: the average is the calculation of the gap between of each transaction for each buyer(createdby) with the amount of the transaction, on that case there's total 6 days over 4 gap transaction, so the average are 1,5

Comment: so based on that data dummy, the average for each buyer to doing his new transaction from his last transaction are 1,5 day after his last transaction in range date 2018-12-01 until 2018-12-04

Comment: you have to say which version  of mysql you use, with 8.0  there are window functios that make your query quite easy

Comment: after i check it, it appear version 5.7.23-log