# how to count max and min average and median into the data mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

i have 1 table called order_match which contain order_buyer_Id as the id of the transaction, createdby as the id of the buyer, and createdAt as the date when the transaction happen.

on this case, i want to count of the order (order_buyer_Id) for each buyer (createdby) and find out the maximum and the minumum count after that.

this is the example data:

```
+----------------+-----------+------------+
| order_buyer_id | createdby | createdAt  |
+----------------+-----------+------------+
|          19123 |        19 | 2017-02-02 |
|         193241 |        19 | 2017-02-02 |
|         123123 |        20 | 2017-02-02 |
|          32242 |        20 | 2017-02-02 |
|          32434 |        20 | 2017-02-02 |
+----------------+-----------+------------+
```

and if run the syntax, the expected result are:

```
+-----+-----+---------+--------+
| max | min | average | median |
+-----+-----+---------+--------+
|   3 |   2 |     2,5 |      3 |
+-----+-----+---------+---------
```

i've use with this syntax

```
select max(count(order_buyer_id)), min(count(order_buyer_id)), avg(count(order_buyer_id)), median(count(order_buyer_Id)) from order_match where createdby = 19 and 20 and createdAt = '2017-02-02' group by createdby;
```

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: after i check it, it appear version 5.7.23-log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of what you want to do is straightforward, but to compute median values you need a `ROW_NUMBER` function, which you have to simulate with variables in MySQL 5.7. Having computed the row number (based on ordering counts) you can then take the either the middle count (if there are an odd number of values) or the average of the two middle values (if there are an even number of values) to get the median. By using conditional aggregation, we can then compute the median at the same time as the other values:

```
SELECT MAX(count) AS max,
       MIN(count) AS min,
       AVG(count) AS average,
       AVG(CASE WHEN rn IN (FLOOR((@tr+1)/2), FLOOR((@tr+2)/2)) THEN count END) AS median
FROM (
  SELECT count, 
         @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn,
         @tr := @rn AS tr
  FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM order_match
    GROUP BY createdby
    ORDER BY count
  ) o
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0) init
) c
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
max     min     average     median
3       2       2.5         2.5
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/46c0f1/9)

Comment: thankyou very much sir, if i want to add some condition (like date range) can i just adding some date range after "FROM order_match"?

Comment: @FachryDzakyAl-QadriSabil yes, if you want to add a condition that would be the place for it - between `FROM order_match` and `GROUP BY createdby`

Comment: sir, can you helping me out with this question, just like this but what i want to find out is the difference between dates on each users https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60350526/count-the-differiante-date-of-each-users-mysql @Nick